# Button color wasn't changed after clicking

Tags: java, android, android-button

After clicking button colored wasn't changed by below code.
My code is->

```
public void onClick(View ButtonView){
    ButtonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is my error what I get from "Run" tab in Android studio->
--------- beginning of crash

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.helloworldapp, PID: 16093
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Button(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'onClick'
```

This is my "activity_main.xml" file->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
 
 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/onClick"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="@string/button"
        android:text="@string/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here, what I saw in error that -> My method "onClick" wasn't found.

But how it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` attribute of the `Button` must be set to the click listener method of your activity class. 
So change this:

```
android:onClick="@string/button"
```

to this:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.onClick);

public void onClick() {
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
[MainActivity.java][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnI2h.png

[activity_main.xml][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Rdh.png

Answer (score 0):

The reason for "onClick" wasn't found this error, we haven't linked the click event with the respective method.

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

this will link the `onclick()` Method in the Activity